# Equal width plot sizes in pyplot, while keeping aspect ratio equal

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to have two plots be the same width, however the resulting code shrinks the imshow plot.

```
xx = np.linspace(0.0,255.5,512)
yy = np.linspace(0.0,255.5,512)
Func = np.random.rand(len(xx),len(yy))

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,1)
f.tight_layout()

im = axarr[0].imshow(Func, cmap = 'jet', interpolation = 'lanczos',origin = 'lower')
pos = axarr[0].get_position()
colorbarpos = [pos.x0+1.05*pos.width,pos.y0,0.02,pos.height]
cbar_ax = f.add_axes(colorbarpos)
cbar = f.colorbar(im,cax=cbar_ax)

axarr[1].plot(xx,Func[:,255],yy,Func[255,:])

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

EDIT: I would also like to keep imshow's plot from looking stretched (essentially, I need the width and length stretched appropriately so the aspect ratio's are still equal).

Comment: Add `aspect='auto'` to the parameters of `imshow`.

Comment: This stretches the plot, I guess I need to edit my question, I would like it to be stretched to agree in length on x, but have the correct aspect be maintained.

Comment: This would require the height ratios betzween the plots to be different, so you either need a larger figure or you need to shrink the second plot. Is that what you want?

Comment: I would prefer a larger figure rather than shrinking the second plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options:

#### A. `aspect="auto"

Use `aspect="auto" on the imshow plot

```
    plt.imshow(...,  aspect="auto")
```

[image]

#### B. adjust the figure margings

Adjust the figure margings or the figure size, such that the lower axes will have the same size as the imshow plot, e.g.

```
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.35, right=0.65)
```

[image]

#### C. using a divider

You can use `make_axes_locatable` functionality from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` to divide the image axes to make space for the other axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

xx = np.linspace(0.0,255.5,512)
yy = np.linspace(0.0,255.5,512)
Func = np.random.rand(len(xx),len(yy))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,5))

im = ax.imshow(Func, cmap = 'jet', interpolation = 'lanczos',origin = 'lower')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
ax2 = divider.append_axes("bottom", size=0.8, pad=0.3)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size=0.08, pad=0.1)

ax2.plot(xx,Func[:,255],yy,Func[255,:])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im,cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my question slightly, either solution stretches and what I really want is to make imshow larger while keeping its aspect ratio equal.

Comment: Just wanted to add that option C works excellently for all flavors of plots, not just imshow. Excellent post.